# Access site with localhost and host name

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a site in IIS.
I defined a binding with host name "aaa.com".

My question is how do I access 'http://localhost' and have it refer to the same path as http://example.com which works?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about redirecting from http://aaa.com to your site hosted somewhere? Do you want to know how to reference (from within your pages) to current site (to be independent from actual location)? Do you want to be redirected from localhost to aaa.com automatically? Something else?

Comment: maybe add http://localhost as a host header for the site?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing you hosts file

open the file (it's probably in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc)

find the following line:

`# 127.0.0.1 localhost`

and change it to

`127.0.0.1 aaa.com`

Comment: :| :| :| "... **change it to** ...". This will break any application that relies on "localhost"...I can't understand what he needs but I don't think he needs THIS!